# Adding a full width row to a CollectionView two-column structure

Tags: swift, xcode

I created such a structure with CollectionView, there are two items in one line. The whole structure should go on like this, everything is fine until here, but I must add (only 1) slide at the top. So I want to place one more full width image in 1 line. What path should I follow?

[An image of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xOwi.png)

Comment: By CollectionView you mean UICollectionView, so you're using UIKit, not SwiftUI, right?

Comment: @VadimBelyaev yes im using UIKit, right

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the full-width image that you need to display is just a first item of the data set you're displaying, make the collection view return a custom size for it based on its index path. In order to do it, assign a delegate to your collection view and implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol, specifically the `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` method. Alternatively, if you're targeting iOS 13+, you can do the same with the `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`, but the implementation will be different, in that case I encourage you to read its documentation.

If the item doesn't really belong to the data set, better create a section header with just that item inside.

Comment: You are perfect! Thank you so much, can I ask one more question? Can I reduce the vertical spacing on the Storyboard? I set the min spacing for cell to 0 but the 2 items are not didn't get close. (line spacing can be adjusted, but cell spacing is not)

Comment: Not sure which vertical spacing you mean, is it spacing between two adjacent rows of cells?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to talk about the spaces between cells. Like this: https://prnt.sc/1tkming

Comment: Oh I see, I guess it's rather the horizontal spacing than vertical. It's called interitem spacing. For vertically scrollable collection views with flow layout, only minimal interitem spacing can be set, and the collection view will increase it if the items themselves are too narrow. You need to increase the width of the cells in order to decrease the interitem spacing.

Comment: I solved this problem, thank you very much again. But I couldn't solve my first question :) When I apply the collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:) function, I can't find anywhere how to select the first cell and give it cgsize, i think i'm very newbie and i should try simpler things :)

Comment: Collection view calls this method and passes into it an index path of the item that it needs the size for. Check `indexPath.item`, if it equals to zero, then it's the first element in the collection and you need to return a wide size for it, otherwise return a regular size.